# Using coalesce with sequelize on node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, coalesce

I have the following query:

```
select coalesce(round(sum(vdamesatual) / 
       (select count(*)
        from feriados
        where month(data)=month(current_date) and 
        day(data)<day(current_date) and
        diadasemana in(2,3,4,5,6) and
        feriadonacional=0 and 
        uf <> (select distinct uforigem from baseprodutos where Empresa = 'test'))
       * 
       (select count(*)
        from feriados
        where month(data)=month(current_date) and 
        day(data)>=day(current_date) and
        diadasemana in(2,3,4,5,6) and
        feriadonacional=0 and 
        uf <> (select distinct uforigem from baseprodutos where Empresa = 'test'))),0) as projecao
from baseprodutos
where Empresa = 'test' and
UFDest = 'uf' and
Fabricante = 'sample';
```

As you can see I have a coalesce right after the first select, and I am having trouble finding the right way to write this with sequelize; Would you have some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really follow the logic of your query, but the rule in Sequelize is that you can call any function with `sequelize.fn()` so a simple example of using COALESCE in Sequelize to get a value from 2 columns with an alias would be like this in your `attributes`:

```
[[sequelize.fn('COALESCE', mysql.col('col_name'), mysql.col('col_2_name')), 'alias'], 'another_col']
```

You can include another function if needed, like `SUM` by doing like this:

```
 [[sequelize.fn('COALESCE', sequelize.fn('SUM', (mysql.col('col_name'), mysql.col('col_2_name'))), (some other code here ...)),'alias']]
```